# How to quit `whiptail --gauge`?

Tags: command-line

I have this little example script:

```bsh
for i in {1..100}; do
   echo $i
   sleep 0.1
done | whiptail --gauge "Doing something" 10 50 0
```

It works as it should, displaying a moving progress bar and quits when it reached 100.

Using the same for-loop without piping it to `whiptail`, I can stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. But how can I interactively terminate the process piping to whiptail as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not working here?

Comment: Maybe it’s possible to add a “Cancel” button to `--gauge` anyhow?

Comment: @dessert I have try it, not possible

Comment: Just out of curiosity, *why* do you want to be able to quit `whiptail --gauge`? Its only purpose is displaying the progress, if you want to cancel an operation you should rather stop the process piping to `whiptail`, i.e. the `for` loop. Try killing `whiptail` with `pkill whiptail` once to see how it leaves your terminal while the `for` loop of course still runs.

Comment: There are option to add cancel button, but button not appears when using --gauge

Comment: @dessert If it will be an interactive script, that's very confusing user of not able to break

Comment: It's not about quitting whiptail, but terminating the process piping to whiptail. I made it more clear in the question. I can open another terminal, and manually search for that process and kill it, but I was wondering if there is an easier method.

Comment: An strace on `whiptail` shows that it deliberately ignores signals from `/dev/tty`. There is another similar tool, `dialog`, that does not do this and that you can interrupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have try different optiuons with whiptail, and seems the only solution is to execute it for every percent. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is working.
Changing TERM is needed to make it work in `gnome-terminal`, same for xterm(tested it), and probably other terminals
Tested in text console(tty) - it already have TERM=linux
`whiptail` restores terminal text to same as before execution, but TERM=linux blocks this feature.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {1..100}; do
   sleep 0.1
   export TERM=linux
   echo $i | whiptail --gauge "Doing something" 10 50 $i
done
```

If you need to output some progress information, its better to do it inside `whiptail` text parameters

Comment: doesn't display anything, probably because `echo` quits before `whiptail` shows anything.

Comment: I have tested it, it display only progress bar, not the output of echo

Comment: echo must quit, whiptail displays percent and also quit. This allows to use ctr-c

Comment: yes, ctrl-c works, but it doesn't display whiptail

Comment: I have it working in eclipse terminal plugin, but when check in gnome terminal its really not working. Don't known why yet.

Comment: I make it working in gnome-terminal by changing $TERM. I have also trying to add a sleep after echo, without changing $TERM, it shows up, but blinking

Comment: Works well for me, but I put `export TERM=linux` before the loop. `echo` before `sleep` also works and is better option for me.

Comment: It will cause blinking.

Answer (score 0):

To quit the program you can try something like the following:

```
   for i in {1..100}; do
   echo $i
   sleep 0.1
   read -t 0.1 -N 1 input
   if [[ $input == 'q' ]] || [[ $input == "Q" ]];then
        break;
   fi
done | whiptail --gauge "Doing something. press 'q' or 'Q' to exit" 10 50 0
```

Here the script will wait for user input 'q' or 'Q' to exit.

Comment: Interesting idea, but `sleep 0.1` is just an example. It might be `long_running_command`, and then it won't work instantly, but only at the end of each iteration.